# The $map-$max vs $group-$max in MongoDB! Which is better?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to store time series data (price changes over the datetime) in MongoDB. I can do this in at least two ways:

**Method 1:** (store the price data of each date separately in a field):

```
{ 
  "item" : "I1",
  "Price" : {
         "2020-07-01": [{"t":t1, "v":1000}, {"t":t2, "v":1500}, {"t":t3, "v":1350}, ..],
         "2020-07-02": [{"t":t1, "v":1200}, {"t":t2, "v":1250}, {"t":t3, "v":1050}, ..],         
         ...
     } 
 },
 { 
   "item" : "I2",
   "Price" : {
         "2020-07-01": [{"t":t1, "v":1025}, {"t":t2, "v":1200}, {"t":t3, "v":1400}, ..],
         "2020-07-02": [{"t":t1, "v":1560}, {"t":t2, "v":1050}, {"t":t3, "v":1350}, ..],
         ...
     }
 }
```

**Method 2:** (for each price change, store the date value in price array)

```
{ 
  "item" : "I1",
  "Price" : [
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t1, "v":1000}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t2, "v":1500}, 
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t1, "v":1200},
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t2, "v":1250},
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-04", "t":t1, "v":1050}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-04", "t":t2, "v":1400},  
          ...
      ] 
 },
 { 
   "item" : "I2",
   "Price" : [
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t1, "v":1025}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t2, "v":1200},           
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t1, "v":1560}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t2, "v":1050}, 
          ...
      ]
 }
```

Now, I want to get maximum value of prices over a period.
In method 1, I can do this using $objectToArray and $map in MongoDB:

```
'$max': {
    '$map': {
        'input': { '$objectToArray': '$Price' },
        'in': { '$max': '$$this.v' }
     }
 }
```

However, In method 2, I can do it easily using $group and $max!

I am curious to know whether **$map-$max is better or $group-$max**?
Storing data in method 1 has the advantage that I can easily and quickly access to data of each date using price['date']. However, I am not sure for some queries over a periods of time (as above mentioned), the queries for method 1 be as fast as queries in method 2 (because for these queries we should use $objectToArray)!
I will be thankful if you share your experiences.

Comment: Well, your 1st method doesn't count with `$$this.k`, so it should be: `in: {'$max':'$$this'}`. Any transformation before `$match`, `$sort` or `$group` doesn't allow usage of indexes. If document `item` is unique, both methods have the same performance, since MongoDB needs to scan entire collection.

Comment: Good, But I think if we define index on "Price.d", then the second method should be faster. Is it True? @Valijon